# MySQL slave_open_temp_tables always shows 1

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a MySQL database set up for testing xtrabackup. The database is MySQL 5.5.52.

It is configured as a slave, however, there is very little in the way of replication (1 query every 10 seconds).

During the last test of xtrabackup (last night) it failed to complete due to:

```
180606 01:05:18 Slave open temp tables: 1
180606 01:05:18 Slave_open_temp_tables did not become zero after 300 seconds
```

Looking at the the database now, it is still showing `Slave_open_temp_tables = 1`.

I have tried restarting replication, and flushing the tables and logs. But it insists on staying at 1.

In the end I was forced to restart the database entirely, and that fixed the problem.

Is there a better way of 'flushing' this status without needing to resort to a full restart.

Comment: A possible work-around: Reading this documentation page: [Replication and Temporary Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-features-temptables.html), it seems that you can avoid that temporary tables are created on the slave in the first place by using `binlog_format=ROW`. Is that an option? Would be interested to hear if that helps the issue.

Comment: that is planned for the future, but we're not ready for that yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to do this.

```
STOP SLAVE;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS;
```

write down `relay_master_log_file` and `exec_master_log_pos`

```
RESET SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE = 'relay_master_log_file', MASTER_LOG_POS = exec_master_log_pos;
START SLAVE;
```

And now it reports `Slave_open_temp_tables` AS 0.

Comment: Did you try simply `STOP SLAVE; START SLAVE;`?  Or was `RESET` a key factor?

Comment: No, it needed the reset.